# Check what thread a method is being called from

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a method that I only want to have called when not on the main thread (does heavy work) and if it is called from the main thread I would throw a runtime exception, similar to what happens when you try to do a network call on the main thread and you get a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`

I have not found anything on this issue so is there a way to do it?

Comment: @Akshay did you even read my question!? this has nothing to do with my question

Comment: @tyczj Sorry, I was reading too quickly and misunderstood, my apologies. I've added an answer below that hopefully addresses your question more properly.

Comment: @NiekHaarman I guess I should have searched "UI thread" instead of "main thread"

Comment: Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare the current thread with the one of the main `Looper`

```
if (Thread.currentThread() == Looper.getMainLooper().getThread())
    throw new IllegalStateException();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Thread.currentThread()` to get a reference to the current thread. If you remember the the main thread on start you can verify that the method is being called from the correct one.

For instance, you could write:

```
// At the start of the main thread, keep a reference

Thread mainThread;

public void mainThreadMethod()
{
    mainThread = Thread.currentThread();
    // ...
}

// In the relevant method, check the thread you're on

public void myMethod()
{
    if(Thread.currentThread().equals(mainThread))
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Method called from main thread");
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Why bother with the ID?  Why not just compare the actual Thread object?

Comment: @jameslarge I've always thought IDs are easier to store. I guess you could compare the actual `Thread`s if you really wanted to.

Comment: I would really want to compare the actual Thread because it's fewer method calls.  As for storing:  On a 64-bit platform, the size of a Thread reference will be the same as the size of a long.  On a 32-bit platform, the Thread reference might actually be smaller.

Comment: @jameslarge Interesting, I didn't actually know that. I'll update my answer accordingly.